# Strategy to update previous screens in react native when new form entries added

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation, react-state-management, stack-navigator

I have a use case where I am using stack navigator. I have a homepage where I have some aggregated data and a list which are retrieved from an API.
On clicking on a list item I move to a screen which has more details of that item. There I can add entries for that item. When entries are added using a form, both the homepage as well as the item specific screen need to be updated, which means I need to call the API's again to fetch data. In case no transactions are added I was to avoid this.

What should be the best practice here? should I pass a state variable from homepage and whenever it is updated refresh the screens?
Currently, I am using a willFocus listener, and it makes an API call each time I am on one of these screens. I believe that there can be a better approach than this.

Comment: You can try using redux-saga to dispatch a call to API given action is done.

Comment: You should keep your data in a global store like redux or mobx-state-tree, when adding the item via API, it should also add the item to the local store if it succeeded. This way, your components will automatically update if data changes without extra calls to API on focus.